# MongoDB - shutting down by failed Only one usage of each socket address

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, express

Hii I'm Beginner in MEAN Stack Development
I'm not getting connected with server

```
c:\MongoDB\bin>mongod
2017-11-09T20:28:32.450+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1004 port=27017 dbpath=c:\data\db\ 64-bit host=Krishna-PC
2017-11-09T20:28:32.450+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2017-11-09T20:28:32.451+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.10
2017-11-09T20:28:32.451+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 078f28920cb24de0dd479b5ea6c66c644f6326e9
2017-11-09T20:28:32.452+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1u-fips  22 Sep 2016
2017-11-09T20:28:32.456+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-11-09T20:28:32.458+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-11-09T20:28:32.460+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-11-09T20:28:32.460+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
2017-11-09T20:28:32.460+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-11-09T20:28:32.461+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-11-09T20:28:32.461+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-11-09T20:28:32.463+0530 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/por
t) is normally permitted. for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2017-11-09T20:28:32.463+0530 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets during startup.
2017-11-09T20:28:32.470+0530 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: InternalError: Failed to set up sockets
2017-11-09T20:28:32.475+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-11-09T20:28:32.477+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-11-09T20:28:32.477+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-11-09T20:28:32.477+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:48
D:\project>nodemon server.js
[nodemon] 1.12.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
(node:4860) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using
`connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
Server is Running on 3000
```

I'm trying build a project Please support
Thank in advance

Comment: Yes I did some research actually but didn't worked so i came here for suggestion 
What I found is at Resource monitor is also not allowing the port a firewall satus at linkin ports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on :

```
2017-11-09T20:28:32.463+0530 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/por
t) is normally permitted. for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
```

**Problem**

Your MongoDB database is already started on port `27017` or you have another process on your server using the MongoDB port `27017`.

**Solution**

If the port 27017 is already used by another process, you can change the port when you start your MongoDB database.

You can check the documentation : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-port

> ```
> --port <port>
> ```
>
> *Default: 27017*
>
> Specifies the TCP port on which the MongoDB instance listens for
>   client connections.

Comment: Can you connect to the database with a mongo shell ?

Comment: Please Guide me To Show the Code

Comment: Did you create `sampledb` inside your MongoDB database ?

Comment: Its not connecting through it